# Variable triggers replacement of values

Tags: bash, curl, metadata

I have custom meta data on my compute engine instance with key `json` and value `{ "a" : " * * * " }`.

[image]

Now when I do :

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/json" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Result :

```
{ "a" : " * * * " }
```

which is what you'd expect.

But now **I want to get this value into a variable** :

```
JSON=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/json" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

and the value of the variable JSON is :

```
{ "a" : " file_ind_dir1 file_ind_dir2 file_ind_dir1 file_ind_dir2 file_ind_dir1 file_ind_dir2 " }
```

**So the * (asterix) in the value of my custom meta data is being replaced with the listing of the current directory !!**

Is this a bug on my end in the way I assign the variable or is Compute Engine to blame here.

**Really don't see what triggers this replacement.**

PS: did a couple more tests and only a wildcard with preceding space seems to exhibit this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using `echo $JSON` instead of `echo "$JSON"` to display the value of the variable.